# Informações de musicas

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um player de música e apareceu uma dificuldade para captar as informações das músicas.

  Estou usando um ContentResolver e um Cursor para fazer as buscas de músicas na memória do dispositivo. As informações como nome, título, artista e outros e consigo captar normal, já que o próprio Cursor retorna essas informações, com exceção do Álbum.

  O problema é para captar o Gênero(estilo musical). Para isso uso o MediaMetadataRetriever, porém ele está retornando valores estranhos.

  No caso do Álbum, a informação é captada com o Cursor, porém quando o arquivo não possui um nome de álbum salvo, ele retorna o gênero musical.

  No caso do Gênero, ele retorna números em alguns estilos musicais, por exemplo: Quando é um hip-hop ele retorna (5), quando rap, retorna (7) e por ai vai.


 A dúvida é: Como faço para captar essa informações de maneira correta? Abaixo segue o código da leitura da músicas

```
private void lerMusicas() {
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int nameColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int folderColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);


        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            String thisAlbumArtist = "";
            String thisAlbum = musicCursor.getString(albumColumn);
            String thisName = musicCursor.getString(nameColumn);
            Uri thisUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(musicUri, thisId);
            String thisGender = "";
            String thisFolder = musicCursor.getString(folderColumn);

            try {
                MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                retriever.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, thisUri);
                if (retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE) != null)
                    thisGender = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE);
                else thisGender = "<unknown>";
                if (retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST) != null)
                    thisAlbumArtist = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST);
                else thisAlbumArtist = "<unknown>";

                retriever.release();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                // something went wrong with the file, ignore it and continue
            }

            todasMusicas.add(new Music(thisId, thisName, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisAlbumArtist, thisAlbum, thisGender, thisFolder, thisUri));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Ps.: Em um ViewPager, as informações são exibidas em um ListView, onde é exibido apenas uma informação por Fragment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728921/get-the-genre-of-a-song/19743031

Comment: nem todos os arquivos possuem os metadados completos, estas informações dependem totalmente que o autor(ou terceiro) insira essas informações no áudio